# ways to go from A to B(harder version proof)

Tags: combinatorics

I want to go from $A$ to $B$ using shortest way in a $m*n$ way.

**conditon**:If you do two moves like $ru$ you cannot do your next two moves  like that for example you should do $ur$, $rr$ or $uu$ I want a formula that how many ways are there?

Comment: Which are the options for direction?

Comment: shortest way means just up or right

Comment: oh right, ok$ {}{}{}$

Comment: So do you mean that you want all paths from $A$ to $B$ that do not contain $urur$, $ruru$, $rrrr$, or $uuuu$?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: @TahaAkbari Why don't you use MathJax and properly format your questions ?

Comment: I don't know where to study MathJax.

Comment: A very useful link to learn how to work with MathJax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference